# PHP and MYSQL calculate total of month and copy it to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have table (orders): id, price, date

```
id  |  price  |   date

01  |  250    |  2013-01-25

02  |  350    |  2013-01-25

03  |  25     |  2013-02-03

04  |  14     |  2013-03-21

05  |  96     |  2013-08-12

06  |  37     |  2013-08-12

07  |  89     |  2013-08-28

08  |  78     |  2013-12-20

09  |  45     |  2013-12-21
```

I want to output everytime that I execute scrip:

- total price of single day
- total price of single month
- total price of year.

I'd like to insert all days total in another table like this one with all year days (for ex.):

```
date        |  price

2013-01-01  |  5656

2013-01-02  |  659596

2013-01-03  |  5464
```

For day total I used this code

```
...ecc..

$date = date("Y-m-d");

....ecc...

$query = "SELECT id, price FROM orders WHERE delivery_date LIKE '%$date%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

...ecc...
```

but I can do it only for current date, not for any daye.
And I cannot do  it for anty month..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

To get the `SUM` of prices for each day you can do:

```sql
SELECT date, SUM(price) as price
FROM orders 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9454/1)</kbd>

This will get you the date and the total sum of prices for that date, as long as there is any item in that date.

To insert it into another table you can do:

```sql
INSERT INTO tab2
SELECT date, SUM(price) as price
FROM orders 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thanks. how can i populate other table with all this output?

Comment: @user2964048. I added the query to Insert to the answer

Comment: sorry but I have calculated day total by PHp ( i cannot do it by SUM becaouse I must make conversion value before) I have total pay on PHP variable, it is $total, how can I do it?

Comment: Do insert into tab2 values($date,$total);

Comment: ok, works, but i must insert it for all days, not today. this one works for only one row.. i must populate new table with all 2013 days

Comment: I'm not fluent in php. If you want to do it in sql you can do the query i wrote in the answer and do the conversions in sql inside the SUM().